# Interact within range of values - Pentaho Kettle

Tags: sql, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a table where it contains minimum and maximum account values ​​to organize within a classification, I want to interact with this value to generate the accounts within the range.

| ORDEM | ABC MIN_CONTA | ABC MAX_CONTA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 102 | 0000132000 | 0000132012 |
| 102 | 0000132014 | 0000132021 |
| 102 | 0000132030 | 0000132031 |
| 102 | 0000132050 | 0000132051 |
| 102 | 0000132200 | 0000132202 |
| 103 | 0000132101 | 0000132112 |
| 103 | 0000132115 | 0000132115 |
| 103 | 0000132118 | 0000132119 |
| 103 | 0000132130 | 0000132130 |
| 104 | 0000134000 | 0000134009 |

It manages to make the change I sought through a script in SQL Server, but I cannot execute it in Pentaho.
Follow the script:

```
DECLARE @COL_MIN INT;
DECLARE @COL_MAX INT;

SELECT @COL_MIN = MIN(CAST(MIN_CONTA AS INT)), @COL_MAX = MAX(CAST(MAX_CONTA AS INT))
FROM EDW.STG.STG_DRE_CONTA_RAZAO_FAGL_011ZC_SAP;

IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#DUMMY_NUMBER') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE #DUMMY_NUMBER
END

CREATE TABLE #DUMMY_NUMBER (NUM INT);

WHILE @COL_MIN <= @COL_MAX
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #DUMMY_NUMBER VALUES (@COL_MIN);
SET @COL_MIN = @COL_MIN+1;
END;

IF OBJECT_ID('EDW.STG.STG_DRE_CONTA_RAZAO_FINAL', 'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE EDW.STG.STG_DRE_CONTA_RAZAO_FINAL;
END

SELECT * INTO EDW.STG.STG_DRE_CONTA_RAZAO_FINAL
FROM #DUMMY_NUMBER T2 
INNER JOIN EDW.STG.STG_DRE_CONTA_RAZAO_FAGL_011ZC_SAP T1 ON T2.NUM BETWEEN CAST(T1.MIN_CONTA AS INT) AND CAST(T1.MAX_CONTA AS INT);

DROP TABLE #DUMMY_NUMBER;
```

| 123 NUM | ABC ORDEM | ABC MIN_CONTA | ABC MAX_CONTA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111000 | 90 | 0000111000 | 0000111100 |
| 111001 | 90 | 0000111000 | 0000111100 |
| 111002 | 90 | 0000111000 | 0000111100 |
| 111003 | 90 | 0000111000 | 0000111100 |
| 111004 | 90 | 0000111000 | 0000111100 |
| 111005 | 90 | 0000111000 | 0000111100 |
| 111006 | 90 | 0000111000 | 0000111100 |
| 111007 | 90 | 0000111000 | 0000111100 |
| 111008 | 90 | 0000111000 | 0000111100 |
| 111009 | 90 | 0000111000 | 0000111100 |
| 111010 | 90 | 0000111000 | 0000111100 |
| 111011 | 90 | 0000111000 | 0000111100 |
| 111012 | 90 | 0000111000 | 0000111100 |
| 111013 | 90 | 0000111000 | 0000111100 |
| 111014 | 90 | 0000111000 | 0000111100 |
| 111015 | 90 | 0000111000 | 0000111100 |
| 111016 | 90 | 0000111000 | 0000111100 |
| 111017 | 90 | 0000111000 | 0000111100 |
| 111018 | 90 | 0000111000 | 0000111100 |
| 111019 | 90 | 0000111000 | 0000111100 |

```
2023/03/06 08:53:49 - EDW - New database connection defined
2023/03/06 08:53:49 - Execute SQL script 2.0 - Connected to database... 2023/03/06 08:53:49 - EDW - launch DDL statement:  
2023/03/06 08:53:49 - EDW - DECLARE @COL_MIN INT 
2023/03/06 08:53:49 - EDW - launch DDL statement:  
2023/03/06 08:53:49 - EDW - DECLARE @COL_MAX INT 
2023/03/06 08:53:49 - EDW - launch SELECT statement:  
2023/03/06 08:53:49 - EDW - SELECT @COL_MIN = MIN(CAST(MIN_CONTA AS INT)), @COL_MAX = MAX(CAST(MAX_CONTA AS INT)) 
2023/03/06 08:53:49 - EDW - FROM EDW.STG.STG_DRE_CONTA_RAZAO_FAGL_011ZC_SAP 2023/03/06 08:53:49 - Execute SQL script 2.0 - ERROR (version 8.0.0.0-28, build 8.0.0.0-28 from 2017-11-05 07.27.50 by buildguy) : An error occurred, processing will be stopped:  
2023/03/06 08:53:49 - Execute SQL script 2.0 - An error occurred executing SQL:  
2023/03/06 08:53:49 - Execute SQL script 2.0 - SELECT @COL_MIN = MIN(CAST(MIN_CONTA AS INT)), @COL_MAX = MAX(CAST(MAX_CONTA AS INT)) 
2023/03/06 08:53:49 - Execute SQL script
2.0 - FROM EDW.STG.STG_DRE_CONTA_RAZAO_FAGL_011ZC_SAP 
2023/03/06 08:53:49 - Execute SQL script 2.0 - Must declare the scalar variable "@COL_MIN". 
2023/03/06 08:53:49 - EDW - Statement canceled! 
2023/03/06 08:53:49 - EDW - Statement canceled! 
2023/03/06 08:53:49 - Execute SQL script 2.0 - ERROR (version 8.0.0.0-28, build 8.0.0.0-28 from 2017-11-05 07.27.50 by buildguy) : Error initializing step [Execute SQL script 2] 
2023/03/06 08:53:49 - TRF_DIM_DRE_CONTA_RAZAO_SAP - Step [Script.0] initialized flawlessly. 
2023/03/06 08:53:49 - TRF_DIM_DRE_CONTA_RAZAO_SAP - ERROR (version 8.0.0.0-28, build
8.0.0.0-28 from 2017-11-05 07.27.50 by buildguy) : Step [Execute SQL script 2.0] failed to initialize! 
2023/03/06 08:53:49 - TRF_DIM_DRE_CONTA_RAZAO_SAP - Step [Dummy (do nothing).0] initialized flawlessly. 
2023/03/06 08:53:49 - TRF_DIM_DRE_CONTA_RAZAO_SAP - Step [Join Rows (cartesian product).0] initialized flawlessly. 
2023/03/06 08:53:49 - Execute SQL script 2.0 - Finished reading query, closing connection. 
2023/03/06 08:53:49 - EDW - Connection to database closed! 
2023/03/06 08:53:49 - Spoon - ERROR (version 8.0.0.0-28, build
8.0.0.0-28 from 2017-11-05 07.27.50 by buildguy) : TRF_DIM_DRE_CONTA_RAZAO_SAP: preparing transformation execution failed 
2023/03/06 08:53:49 - Spoon - ERROR (version 8.0.0.0-28, build
8.0.0.0-28 from 2017-11-05 07.27.50 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException:  
2023/03/06 08:53:49 - Spoon - We failed to initialize at least one step.  Execution can not begin! 
2023/03/06 08:53:49 - Spoon -  
2023/03/06 08:53:49 - Spoon -  
2023/03/06 08:53:49 - Spoon -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.Trans.prepareExecution(Trans.java:1163) 
2023/03/06 08:53:49 - Spoon -   at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.trans.TransGraph$29.run(TransGraph.java:4202)
2023/03/06 08:53:49 - Spoon -   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 
2023/03/06 08:53:49 - TRF_DIM_DRE_CONTA_RAZAO_SAP - ERROR (version 8.0.0.0-28, build
8.0.0.0-28 from 2017-11-05 07.27.50 by buildguy) : Errors detected! 
2023/03/06 08:53:49 - TRF_DIM_DRE_CONTA_RAZAO_SAP - ERROR (version
8.0.0.0-28, build 8.0.0.0-28 from 2017-11-05 07.27.50 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
```

I try to carry out this interaction of the range, through chatgpt he informed me of another method to carry out, but it does not manage to flow, follow the comment:
'Add a "Row generator" node to the transformation and configure it to generate sequential numbers according to the minimum and maximum values ​​of "MIN_CONTA" and "MAX_CONTA" obtained in the previous step. To do so, create two variables in the "Row generator" node: "start_num" and "end_num", and configure them to receive the minimum and maximum values ​​of "MIN_CONTA" and "MAX_CONTA", respectively. Then, select the "Series" option in the "Row generator" node and configure it to generate a sequence of numbers from "start_num" to "end_num". Finally, add a field in the output of the "Row generator" node with the name "num" and the type "Integer".'

I tried to perform an iteration on the table to get the account range numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of friends, he manages to come up with two solutions:

1 - Using the recursive union of a common table to iterate the range values, follow the script:

```
-- Este script utiliza uma CTE (Common Table Expression) para gerar uma lista de números inteiros.
-- A CTE começa com os valores mínimos e máximos de uma determinada coluna de uma tabela de origem.
-- Em seguida, ela se une recursivamente a si mesma, adicionando 1 à cada valor até chegar ao valor máximo.
-- O resultado é uma tabela com uma única coluna de números inteiros.
-- O OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) é adicionado para evitar o erro de recursão máxima atingida. WITH cte AS (
  -- Seleciona os valores mínimos e máximos da coluna de origem e os converte em inteiros.
  SELECT ORDEM, CAST(MIN_CONTA AS INT) AS MIN_CONTA, CAST(MAX_CONTA AS INT) AS MAX_CONTA, CAST(MIN_CONTA AS INT) AS CONTA
  FROM EDW.stg.STG_DRE_CONTA_RAZAO_FAGL_011ZC_SAP   -- Une recursivamente a CTE a si mesma, adicionando 1 à cada valor até chegar ao valor máximo.
  UNION ALL
  SELECT cte.ORDEM, cte.MIN_CONTA, cte.MAX_CONTA, cte.CONTA + 1 AS CONTA
  FROM cte
  WHERE cte.CONTA < cte.MAX_CONTA) -- Seleciona os resultados finais da CTE e os retorna.
SELECT DISTINCT ORDEM, MIN_CONTA, MAX_CONTA, CONTA
FROM cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

2 - We use the "Modified Java Script Value" step and then the "Split field to rows" to create the "CONTA" column with the data from the intersected row.

```
var COL_MIN = MIN_CONTA;
var COL_MAX = MAX_CONTA;


var CONTA_INTERADORA = [];
  for (var i = COL_MIN; i <= COL_MAX; i++) {
    CONTA_INTERADORA.push(i);
  }
```

[image: Step Javascript]

[image: Split Fields]